# How to give type declaration to "nested" rules in Bison?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am using Flex and Bison to create a parser. I want to be able to add variable names to a table when it is declared. I am using the $ symbols to get the values to pass to my addEntry function.

```
%union{
   int num;
   char* str;
}

%token <str> ID
```

I have created an union and declared what type the ID token should be. Below is a snippet of my grammar rules in Bison.

```
decl : kind var_list SEMI
     {addEntry($2);}
     ;

var_list : ID
         | var_list COMMA ID;
```

I want to add $2 which consists of one or more ID (identifiers/variables). Currently, when I compile the code I get an error that var_list does not have a declared type. Is there a way for Bison to match var_list to ID to str? I know I could declare a type for var_list in this example because it only consists of ID but what if var_list could be other things other than str. For example, what if var_list could be ID or INT and the grammar reads in an INT which should be of type . Is there a way for Bison to set var_list to a type based on which rule var_list matches?